# Javascript String to Nested Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I am rolling my own two-way DOM binder to link inputs to JSON as a learning opportunity without using Ember, Angular, KnockoutJS, etc.  I am trying to find a way to recursively build a dynamic array based on the property name.  My JavaScript definitely has a bad code smell with the case statements but I haven't found a better way.

```
"Customer.Id" = parent[Customer][Id]
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    CustomerOrder: {
        Id: 12345,
        Customer: {
            Id: 555
            Name: "Acme"
            Address: "123 Main"
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-dom="CustomerOrder.Id">
<input type="text" data-dom="CustomerOrder.Customer.Name">
```

**Partial JavaScript Code**

```
var checkElements = function () {
    $("[data-dom]").each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var result;
        var ary = $element.data("dom").split(".");
        switch (ary.length) {
            case 1:
                result = data[ary[0]];
                break;
            case 2:
                result = data[ary[0]][ary[1]];
                break;
            case 3:
                result = data[ary[0]][ary[1]][ary[2]];
                break;
            case 4:
                result = data[ary[0]][ary[1]][ary[2]][ary[3]];
                break;
            default:
                result = data;
                break;
        }
        if ($element.is("input, textarea")) {
            $element.val(result);
            return;
        }
        $element.text(result);
    });
}

$(document).on("keyup", "[data-dom]", function() {
    var ary = $(this).data("dom").split(".");
    switch (ary.length) {
    case 1:
        data[ary[0]] = $(this).val();
        break;
    case 2:
        data[ary[0]][ary[1]] = $(this).val();
        break;
    case 3:
        data[ary[0]][ary[1]][ary[2]] = $(this).val();
        break;
    case 4:
        data[ary[0]][ary[1]][ary[2]][ary[3]] = $(this).val();
        break;
    default:
        data = $(this).val();
        break;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    $(document).trigger("data-dom-change");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the switch function with a recursive one,

```
function returnValue(data, ary, pos) {
  var position = pos || 0;
  if (position === ary.length) {
    return data;
  } 
  return returnValue(data[ary[position]], ary, position+1);
}
```

Next, you can replace switch statements as follows

```
var checkElements = function () {
    $("[data-dom]").each(function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var result;
        var ary = $element.data("dom").split(".");
        var result = returnValue(data,ary);

        if ($element.is("input, textarea")) {
            $element.val(result);
            return;
        }
        $element.text(result);
    });
}

$(document).on("keyup", "[data-dom]", function() {
    var ary = $(this).data("dom").split(".");
    var value = returnValue(data,ary);
    value = $(this).val();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    $(document).trigger("data-dom-change");
});
```